# How to separate my 1 column of time into Data and Time

Tags: r, date

I'm very sorry (I'm brand new), as I understand this has been posted a million times but I want to understand not only the answer, but which methodology I should be using as a best practice. I've clicked 10+ links on how to do this, but I seem to mess it up on my data.

I have 3 columns of data in my heartrate_seconds.csv (ID, Date, Value), my date column is comprised of both the time and date which I'd like to separate (Ex: 4/12/2016 7:22:50 AM)

so far the closest I've been is using

```
heartrate_timeanddate <- heartrate_seconds %>% 
  mutate(Time = as.character(Time)) %>% 
  separate(Time, into = c("Date", "Time"), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(Time = as.Date(Date))
```

but this results in my newly added Time column as a date, how do I change this?

Other methods I tried that failed very early:

```
heartrate_seconds_Time <- separate(heartrate_seconds = df, col = Time, into = c('Date, Time'), sep = ' ')
```

```
heartrate_time <- data.frame(heartrate_seconds, Time = c('Date','Time'))
heartrate_time$date <- as.Date(heartrate_time$all)
heartrate_time$date <- format(as.Date(heartrate_time$all), format ="%H:%M:%S")
```

```
heartrate_seconds %>% 
  separate(Time, into = c('Date, Time'), sep = '\\\\') %>% 
  select(Date, Time)
```

I feel I'm using other peoples methods from other posts incorrectly and it's just pushed me into further confusion. So I've come seeking clarity. Thank you so much!

All of this just because I couldn't import the .csv into SQL, which I probably could've fixed in the schema but 1 thing at a time I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I would use either `separate` or the `lubridate` package.

##### `tidyr::separate`

Use `tidyr::separate` with parameter `extra = "merge"`. This means that if you include less columns in `into`, the remaining information will be kept in the last column. Here, this means you can use it to get two columns with the separator `" "`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate(date, into = c("Date","Time"), extra = "merge", sep = " ")

       Date       Time
1 4/12/2016 7:22:50 AM
2 6/12/2016 7:22:50 PM
```

---

##### `lubridate`

With the lubridate package, you can convert your column to a datetime object easily with `dmy_hms`. Then create new variables with `date` and  `format`.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = dmy_hms(date),
         Date = date(date),
         Time = format(date, format = "%H:%M:%S"))

                 date       Date     Time
1 2016-12-04 07:22:50 2016-12-04 07:22:50
2 2016-12-06 19:22:50 2016-12-06 19:22:50
```

Comment: Using tidyr:separate makes the most sense to me and runs. However, my Time column goes from "4/12/2016 7:21:00 AM" -> 0004-12-20

Comment: I guess it's because you converted your data to a Date format right before? To use the separate option, I'd suggest not to convert to Date object beforehand (let it be a character vector).

Comment: Thanks so much, I got it to work. Slept on it and made some simple errors, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One simple option is to use `separate` as you did, but replace the first space with another character, then separate on that.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(col = str_replace(date, "\\s", "|")) %>% 
  separate(col, into = c("Date", "Time"), sep = "\\|") %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format="%d/%m/%Y"))
```

**Output**

```
                  date       Date       Time
1 4/12/2016 7:22:50 AM 2016-12-04 7:22:50 AM
2 6/12/2016 7:22:50 PM 2016-12-06 7:22:50 PM
```

**Data**

```
df <-
  structure(list(date = c(
    "4/12/2016 7:22:50 AM", "6/12/2016 7:22:50 PM"
  )),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-2L))
```

Another option is to use `as.Date` to convert the `date` into a variable of class Date. Then, for time variable, we can use format to extract the time component as a string.

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$date)
df$Time <- format(as.POSIXct(df$date), format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

**Output**

```
                  date       Date     Time
1  2021-05-28 07:16:52 2021-05-28 07:16:52
2  2021-05-30 13:35:00 2021-05-30 13:35:00
3  2021-05-30 14:22:55 2021-05-30 14:22:55
4  2021-05-28 06:51:51 2021-05-28 06:51:51
5  2021-05-30 13:31:55 2021-05-30 13:31:55
6  2021-05-30 13:33:38 2021-05-30 13:33:38
7  2021-05-30 13:35:51 2021-05-30 13:35:51
8  2021-05-30 13:38:44 2021-05-30 13:38:44
9  2021-05-30 13:51:19 2021-05-30 13:51:19
10 2021-05-30 14:04:53 2021-05-30 14:04:53
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1622186212, 1622381700, 1622384575, 
                                        1622184711, 1622381515, 1622381618, 1622381751, 1622381924, 1622382679, 
                                        1622383493), 
                                      tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), 
                row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  When running heartrate_timeanddate <- heartrate_seconds %>% 
  mutate(col = str_replace(date, "\\s", "|")) %>% 
  separate(col, into = c("Date", "Time"), sep = "\\|") %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format="%d/%m/%Y"))                                                                   I get "x argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)"

Comment: @JoshuaSamways It's hard to know without knowing structure of your date column. Can you edit your question and provide some of the data? To just provide a little, you can just do `dput(head(heartrate_seconds))`. Then, I can test it. Or you can try making the column a character first, before running the lines above (i.e., `mutate(date = as.character(date))`).